# Retriving data from XML with Classic ASP

Tags: xml, parsing, asp-classic

I am trying to retrive data from an XML file with classic ASP and xml is almost 10 mb.

I am receiving some of thousands of records without any problem but at one point the script just stops and gives the error "Object Required error 800a01a8" at line 23

23 is the same as others :

```
Dim barkod1 : barkod1 = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("barkod").text
```

The Whole script is here:

```html
<%   

Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")    
objXMLDoc.async = False    
objXMLDoc.load Server.MapPath("ProductList3.xml")

Dim xmlProduct       
For Each xmlProduct In objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("urun")

  Dim sira : sira = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("sira").text   
     Dim urunKodu1 : urunKodu1 = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("urunKodu1").text   
     Dim ureticikodu : ureticikodu = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("ureticikodu").text   
     Dim urunAdi : urunAdi = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("urunAdi").text   
     Dim fiyat1 : fiyat1 = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("fiyat1").text   
     Dim fiyatcinsi1 : fiyatcinsi1 = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("fiyatcinsi1").text   
     Dim kdvdurumu : kdvdurumu = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("kdvdurumu").text   
     Dim kdvorani : kdvorani = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("kdvorani").text   
     Dim garantisuresi : garantisuresi = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("garantisuresi").text   
     Dim stok : stok = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("stok").text
     Dim birim : birim = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("birim").text
     Dim marka : marka = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("marka").text
     Dim katmannumarsi : katmannumarsi = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("katmannumarsi").text
     Dim barkod1 : barkod1 = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("barkod").text
     Dim resim0 : resim0 = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("resim0").text
     Dim resim1 : resim1 = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("resim1").text
     
          
  
     Response.Write "<b>Sıra:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(sira) & "<br> "
     Response.Write "<b>urunKodu1:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(urunKodu1) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>ureticikodu:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(ureticikodu) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>urunAdi:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(urunAdi) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>fiyat1:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(fiyat1) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>fiyatcinsi1:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(fiyatcinsi1) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>kdvdurumu:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(kdvdurumu) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>kdvorani:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(kdvorani) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>garantisuresi:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(garantisuresi) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>Stok:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(stok) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>birim:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(birim) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>marka:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(marka) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>Barkod:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(barkod1) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>resim0:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(resim0) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>resim1:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(resim1) & "<br>"   
     Response.Write "<b>katmannumarsi:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(katmannumarsi) & "<br>---------------<br>"   
     
Next
```

I dont know at which point i am failing but i think it could be the because of the original XML file size so maybe i can hold the script for a while until xml is completely loaded then run my script? what do you guys think?

Here's the example record from the original XML file

```html
<root><urun><sira>0000000</sira><urunKodu1>2000021</urunKodu1><ureticikodu>ABC</ureticikodu><urunAdi>ABC</urunAdi><fiyat1>1,00</fiyat1><fiyatcinsi1>USD</fiyatcinsi1><kdvdurumu>0</kdvdurumu><kdvorani>18</kdvorani><garantisuresi>0</garantisuresi><stok>5+</stok><birim>ADET</birim><marka>XYZ</marka><katmannumarsi>8000</katmannumarsi><barkod>8697671413127</barkod><resim0>https://www.XXX.XX.XX/AAA/BBB/S/21_1.jpg</resim0><resim1>https://www.XXX.XX.XX/AAA/BBB/L/21_1.jpg</resim1><ozellik tanim="Kategori">ABC </ozellik><ozellik tanim="Marka">ABC</ozellik><ozellik tanim="Açıklama">-</ozellik><ozellik tanim="Model Link">-</ozellik><ozellik tanim="Model Soft">-</ozellik><ozellik tanim="Model Dosya">-</ozellik></urun></root>
```

Comment: I think that the problem is that one selectSingleNode don't find the element and give you an error when accessing to text properties. Try to make a function that get the node name and the document, chech that the node exist and if yes return the text. If you would you can add a log for the null nodes

Comment: spent some time on it but the element with "barkod" does exist.. also made spellcheck but wont find anything

Comment: just added example record from the original XML file.

Comment: Well, it suffices that there is one `urun` that does not have a `barkod` child, then you will get that error.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. There are some records without "barkod" How can i check if the record has the "barkod" if it does not exist and can fill it with something else in order not to get error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function like this to get the text if node exists:

```
function getText(theNode)
    if theNode is Nothing then
        getText=""
    else
        getText = theNode.text
    end if
end function
```

And use it like :

```
'Pass the node in the function
Dim barkod1 : barkod1 = getText(xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("barkod"))
```

OR

```
function getText(theNodeName)

    Dim theNodeObj
    set theNodeObj = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode(theNodeName)

    if theNodeObj is Nothing then
        getText=""
    else
        getText = theNodeObj.text
    end if

end function
```

and use it like:

```
'Pass the name in the function
Dim barkod1 : barkod1 = getText("barkod")
```